# why does this c++ code snippet compile with std=c++17 but fails to compile with std=c++20?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, designated-initializer

In godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/bY1a3e1Wz

the code in question is below (the error message says "error: either all initializer clauses should be designated or none of them should be" but I dont understand what it is saying..

```
struct A {
    int a;
    bool b;
};

struct B : A {
    long c;
};

int main(void) {
    B foo {{.a = 1, .b = false}, .c = 7};
}
```

Comment: The code is not valid standard C++17 at all. It wasn't possible to initialize with the `.x =` designated initializer syntax before C++20. Your compiler just accepted it as a language extension and the rules for that language extension are different than the rules in standard C++20 for designated initializers. Compile with the `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` flag if you don't want GCC to accept such language extensions without a warning/error.

Comment: See also: this proposed modification to C++ [P2287](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/978), which, in its latest revision, would create the syntax `B foo{.a = 1, .b = false, .c = 7};`. But it doesn't seem like it'll land for a few years...

Comment: As the error message say, you either need to use designated initializers for all data, or for none. And since it's not possible to use designators for inherited sub-objects you can't use it at all.

Answer (score 4):

From what I see in the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), it looks like this should work:

```
B foo = {{.a = 1, .b = false}, 7};
```

The reason seems to be that the first initializer is "nameless" (by order) and so the second one (`c`) should also be initialized by order rather than by name (it can not be `designated`)